# How to connect Amazon Route 53 to a VPC subnet with routing for different services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, subnet, vpc

I have an Amazon AWS account on with i would like to host my full-stack website, and i also have a domain name, let's assume it is example.com.
I wold like to have a structure like this

```
MyVPC
  |-MySubnetPUBLIC
  |      |-ec2 instance with frontend
  |      |-elastic beanstalk with backend
  |
  |-mySubnetPRIVATE
         |-Database
```

So i have configured my vpc, a router table for mySubnetPUBLIC and an internet gateway and security groups that allow traffic for frontend on port A and for backend on port B. I would like to set route 53 to redirect traffic for example.com to the subnet and let security groups manage the redirection for the different services based on the request port.
I am new to aws, is this something that can be done? How?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a HTTP/HTTPS protocols to connect to your frontend then you can make it accessible by following one of the below 2 options:

**1. Elastic IP**
 - Associate the Elastic IP to the EC2 instance 
 - Using Route53 create a A Record with Elastic IP as value

**2. Load Balancer**
 - Create a Load balancer and associate the EC2 instance to it
 - Using Route53 create a CNAME Record with DNS name of the ELB as value

In either cases, make sure that HTTP and HTTPS traffic is allowed in Inbound and Outbound both at the security groups.

Comment: Thanks Lijo, i got this, but still i have some trouble: rather then associate route 53 with the load balancer directly i would like to associate it to a vpc endpoint and let the security groups allow the access to a resource rather then another, but it seems like not working.

Comment: There is no provision to connect to the VPC from outside world. There are gateway endpoints which are routes to S3 or dynamoDB only. Not clear about what exactly you are looking out for. Please elaborate.